# PUT is undefined

Tags: angular

While I was trying to use `PUT` in my project I was getting this error

```
PUT http://192.168.103.89:8081/users/1/personal-address/undefined
```

My `PUT` request was like this:

```js
 this.userProfileService
      .userAddressInfo_putReq(addressInfoFormdata, this.local_data.userId, this.local_data.addressId)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.addressInfoData = true;
          console.log( this.addressInfoData);
          this.dialogRef.close({ event: 'save'});
```

Comment: Show your userProfileService.userAddressInfo_putReq method

Comment: else if(this.reqMethod=="put"){
      
      this.userProfileService
      .userAddressInfo_putReq(addressInfoFormdata, this.local_data.userId, this.local_data.addressId)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.addressInfoData = true;
          console.log( this.addressInfoData);
          this.dialogRef.close({ event: 'save'});

        },
        error => {
  
        }
      );